# How to use passed value in an expression

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have the following expression that takes the passed value strValue and Selects from the DataRow array;

```
expression = "InvoiceDate='" + strValue + "'"; //value in Locals window = "InvoiceDate='05/28/2013'"
```

I tried to pass the column name as a value as well with this;

```
expression = "'" + strExpression + "'" + strValue + "'"; //value in Locals window = "InvoiceDate='05/28/2013'"

DataRow[] returnedRows; 
returnedRows = theDataConn.DataSet.Tables["Invoices"].Select(expression); //Error
```

which returns a 'Syntax error: Missing operand after '05' operator"

The value in the locals window is the same?? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
expression = strExpression + " = '" + strValue + "'";
```

Notice that I removed `'` before `strExpression` and added `=`

Or use `string.Format()`. Improves readability, helping to avoid typos as those you have on your code

```
expression = string.Format("{0}='{1}'", strExpression, strValue);
```

Comment: Also, @KFP should note that string concatenation is never a good idea beyond very simple cases (two-strings concatenation).